# I cant seem to figure out whats wrong with this piece of code

Tags: pyquery

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging

log_dir = "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/logs/"
logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "key_log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(messages)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    listener.join(key_log)
```

Comment: I'm not sure either, mind describing the issue ?

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)